# Getting the average of the number of attempts using splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Whenever there is an attempt at creating a template, the message "Show Template Creation Dialog" gets logged. I want to get the total number of times that message got logged over a specific period of time. I also want to get the average number of times that message got logged over a period of time. How do I do so using splunk? I want to get this as a single number and not a chart.

```
index="projectm-$env$-ue1"  "Show Template Creation Dialog"
| mvexpand "meta.adobeguid" limit=1
| stats count as "Total", distinct_count("meta.adobeguid") AS "Unique Users"
```

Comment: How does your current query fail to meet your needs?  I can see it does not calculate an average, but the requirements as currently written don't distinguish the time frames for total and average so they can be considered to be the same.

Comment: Instead of stats, if you use chart then you can separate things into different intervals of time easily.